# Scene Boundary Detection

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I'm working on Scene Boundary Detection and following work i have done

**Conventional Approach**: In this approach I've used SSIM and Pearson Coefficient to compare similarity between two frames

Advantages

1. Works well on Abrupt Cut Transitions
2. Fast in execution

Disadvantage
 - False To detect gradual transition(fade-in, fade-out, wipe,dissolve, fast blur)

**Deep SBD**: In this I have implemented deepSBD. Link of the code and paper is https://github.com/abramjos/Scene-boundary-detection

Advantages

1. Works well in Abrupt cut and Gradual Transition.(fade-in, fade-out, wipe,dissolve)

Disadvantage

1. Included manual flash in training due to which wrong detection increases when intensive flash appears in between Frames for eg. Wrestling Videos or sudden sunlight in between shots.
2. Fast Blur motion
3. Long Dissolve Transition

**Transnet**: After that we have implemented Transnet. Link of code and paper is https://github.com/soCzech/TransNet

It replaces some of the wrong detection with correct detection of gradual transition but introduces new problems:

1. Overlap in between frames were wrongly detected as shot change
2. Zoomed transition in between frames were wrongly detected as shot change

**NOTE: AT Last we combined deepSBD and TransNet so None detection is very less but False detection increased because of following**

1. Intensive Flash
2. Fast Motion Blur
3. Zoomed Transition
4. Overlap in between Frames

**Overall Accuracy for 2-3 hours video is expected to be 95% if above problems doesn't appear and if it appears then 70%.**

Is there any way to resolve False detection .